# set azimuth with Exif on image

Tags: android

I need to set the direction value when capture a image from the camera in a tag inside the image. I try for example:

```
  exif.setAttribute("GPSImgDirectionRef","T");

  exif.setAttribute("GPSImgDirection","142.2");
```

with no success.

Any idea?

Thks.

Comment: Could you paste some log stacktrace or code or any errors to specify how it doesn't work? thx

Comment: ss1271, no error appear, but the Exif data is invalid, and doesn't exits (see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) link)

Answer (score 0):

I came into a solution for this issue recently, if someone needs it:

According to `ExifInterface` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) the attribute using the tag `TAG_GPS_IMG_DIRECTION` expects a "rational" value. But as far as I could understand it's source code, it validates the inserted value firstly by checking if there's a "/" char in the string, and after that get the numbers before and after the "/" to generate a double value, and just when it can be converted to a double value this attribute will be added to the image file.

So basically to make it work, instead of sending a `double` value as your attribute, you need to send a fraction.

As a suggestion, making a fraction out of a `double` could be easily done using [Apache Commons Math Lib - Fraction](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/fraction.html). It would be something like this:

```
Fraction azimuthAsFraction = new Fraction(azimuthAsDouble);
exif.setAttribute(TAG_GPS_IMG_DIRECTION, String.valueOf(azimuthAsFraction));
```

This way your azimuth value should be added to the image file metadata.